# Custom XIB View touching UINavigationController

Tags: ios, objective-c, uinavigationcontroller, uitabbarcontroller

I have a custom view:

[image]

That gets placed inside a view controller that is embedded in a `UINavigationController` and `UITabViewController`.

[image]

My custom view is touching my `UINavigationController` and `UITabViewController`. But I would like to have some space between the top and bottom sections. (blue added to show area of the collection view)

[image]

I have moved and removed the constrains. Ensured they are in the safe area.

I have adjusted the `edgesForExtendedLayout`

Here is my code :

```
photosOverview = [[PhotosOverview alloc] initWithFrame:self.view.frame];
[photosOverview.btnAddPhotos addTarget:self action:@selector(buttonPressed:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];
self.edgesForExtendedLayout = UIRectEdgeNone;
[self.view addSubview:photosOverview];
```

***How do I adjust my custom view so there is space between the top and the bottom of its container view?***

Comment: add a vertical contraint to the safe area to have a margin.

Answer (score 0):

Easiest way is, add one view to your photos view controller, with margins(constraints) you require from all sides.

Thereafter, set frames of this new view to your photoOverview, and add photoOverview to that new view.

Check your updated code below, where **newView** is view added to Photos controller.

```
photosOverview = [[PhotosOverview alloc] initWithFrame:self.newView.frame];
[photosOverview.btnAddPhotos addTarget:self action:@selector(buttonPressed:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];
self.edgesForExtendedLayout = UIRectEdgeNone;
[self.newView addSubview:photosOverview];
```